# How do I get the year drop down with a textfield

Tags: grails

I am creating a domain class named HOLIDAY in grails.I need to have a year dropdown in my Holiday year field. Hear is my domain:-

```
class Holiday extends CategoryMaster {

    String holidayName
    Date startDate
    int year
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        holidayName(blank:false, nullable:false)        
    }
}
```

I need to a year dropdown in year field, Should it come dynamically from a domain method that will discard the month & day and reflect only year in that dropdown adding +50 -50 to that?... How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of `Holiday` named `holiday` in scope, you can create the dropdown using something like:

```
<g:select name="year" from="${holiday.year - 50..holiday.year + 50}"
    value="${holiday.year}"/>
```

This will set the current value of the dropdown to `holiday.year` and offer a range 50 years either side of this.

As an aside, if `year` is the year of `startDate`, there is no need to store this as a separate field, as it can easily be computed via:

```
startDate[Calendar.YEAR]
```